# How can I get my google map to move my marker without flickering or page refreshes

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google map api and the following code is code I'm using to move the marker as the coordinates are being updated from my server and stored in variables I'm calling Longitude and Latitude.

The coordinates from my server are being updated from my phone as I move. So I'm trying to create a tracker basically. I've used map.setCenter(latlng); to reduce page refreshes and I think that may have worked but as the marker is set with a new position based on the coordinates sent from the server which is a constant thing, the page still flickers a lot.

What I want is for the map to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bmSbU/268/ but using each new coordinate it's updated with from the Longitude and Latitude variables below that are updated with new coordinates from my server which come from my phone. I'm trying to smoothly track my position. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help.

```
Latitude = //constantly updated from server and contains latitude of my smart phone
Longitude = //constantly updated from server and contains longitude of my smart phone

google.maps.visualRefresh = true;   

/*I start with some random coordinates other than the ones I'm getting from my server
as I felt maybe having coordinates that are different from the ones coming from my    server will allow for me to update with the new coordinates and see a difference */

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.156736,-118.436439);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 15,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
},
panControl: true,
panControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
 },
 zoomControl: true,
 zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
 },
 scaleControl: true,
 streetViewControl: true,
 streetViewControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
 }
 }

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: ''
});


var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude,Longitude);

marker.setPosition(latlng); // Here I'm setting the new position

//map.setCenter(latlng); // I commented out this in attempt to stop page refreshing 

});


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Sort of similar. Although I would like my marker movements to be as smooth as in the fiddle I provided.

Comment: This is a case of needing to do some path interpolation between points, so that you can smoothly animate the movement of the marker.  The fiddle demonstrates that by crudely using a counter to move the marker in tiny increments.  I suggest looking at javascript path animation, or looking for a third party library that would do that.  Here is an example of complex path animation: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/animate-curved-path/